# Why my solution to $\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx$ is incorrect?

Tags: calculus, integration

I was trying to compute$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}~dx$$Naturally, one would try IBP, with $\frac1{1+x^2}$ being integrated: $$\arctan(x)\ln(1+x^2)\bigg|_0^1-\int_0^1\frac{2x\arctan(x)}{1+x^2}~dx$$We then let $u=\arctan x$, $x=\tan u$. So the second integral is $$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}2\tan x~dx=\ln2$$Which is incorrect. Using Desmos, I found that the mistake I am making was the substitution. But what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the integral is: $$\int_0^1\frac{2x\cdot\color{red}{\arctan x}}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$You should obtain: $$\int_0^{\pi/4}2\tan(u)\cdot\color{red}{u}\,\mathrm{d}u$$

Comment: I hate simple mistakes. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @KamalSaleh The simple mistakes become less frequent as you go on, but they never go away entirely. I think it's safe to say we are all victims of them from time to time. I personally know what it's like to bang my head against Desmos for hours trying to determine why my theoretical computations aren't matching the numerics